# img src(unknown) - lost images from probable Wordpress migration

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a site using the [Alice](https://themeforest.net/item/alice-agency-freelance-portfolio-theme/11302841) Wordpress theme run on wordpress.com. I believe the person working on it previously might have migrated it from a previous setup, but I can't be sure.

The issue is the Alice theme is based on using several custom Post types, including things like "Team" and "Portfolio" and "Clients." There are some very nice looking displays for these things [as modeled on the Alice example page](http://demo.az-themes.com/alice/about-creative/). Whenever I add a `Featured Image` to show up in the background of a box for a "Team Member" or "Portfolio Item," the image is broken, and upon inspection is being referred as `img src(unknown)`. If no `Featured Image` is set, the box is displayed well, but obviously blank.

I've been digging through the Alice theme .php files, but I cannot find one that specifies this type of modal on a page. I've found the one that creates the pages for each team member dynamically, but can't find where these image sources are getting lost.

All plugins are up to date, all necessary plugins installed for theme. Everything else is working perfectly, just not these featured images.

Any ideas of where to look or how to test?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. If you have installed JetPack plugin you can deactivate the plugin and try to open.

Also this one can you help you in other way: https://jetpack.com/2013/10/15/add-a-default-fallback-image-if-no-image/

Comment: From Review: Could you please provide the explanation and the steps in that link? Links may get broken, and then your answer may not be useful anymore...